# How do I apply a method or change a property from the string of a variable? vb2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, variables, properties

I need to fill a series of combo boxes with data from the same procedure. I want to do it using a function, so I need to access the add item property of each combo box using a byref variable.

Below is my example:

```
private sub filler(byref combo as string)
    combo.items.add= "something"
end sub
```

the name of the object is inside the combo string.

Comment: What problems are you running into? Is there an error with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code sample here

1. There is no reason to take the `combo` value `ByRef` here because you are not assigning to it.  It is just fine to take it `ByVal` instead
2. Based on the rest of the question I'm guessing the type of `combo` should be `ComboBox` not `String`.
3. You need to invoke the `Add` method not assign to it.

It seems like at the least the code needs to be

```
Private Sub Filler(ByVal combo As ComboBox) 
  combo.Items.Add("Something")
End Sub
```